# Using toUpperCase with Correct Locale

Tags: java

I'm trying to fix errors which are reported by forbiddenapis. I had that line:

```
paramMap.put(Config.TITLEBOOST.toUpperCase(), titleBoost);
```

So, its been reported as error as usual. I've tried that:

```
paramMap.put(Config.TITLEBOOST.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()), titleBoost);
```

and that:

```
paramMap.put(Config.TITLEBOOST.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT), titleBoost);
```

also that:

```
paramMap.put(Config.TITLEBOOST.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH), titleBoost);
```

However none of them fixed the error:

> [forbiddenapis] Forbidden method invocation:
>   java.lang.String#toUpperCase() [Uses default locale]

What I miss?

Comment: what is the error exactly? What is the value of Config.TITLEBOOST?

Comment: Why to downvote? Its a typical forbiddenapis error. They are all same. I've added it to question.

Comment: TITLEBOOST is just a string as well (which has a toUpperCase method).

Comment: Double-check that you have the latest forbiddenapis, that the bytecode you are analyzing is actually your most recent build output, and that you're looking at the same line forbiddenapis is :) .  This looks to me like your source/bytecode/analysis are falling out of sync --- [the rule](https://github.com/policeman-tools/forbidden-apis/blob/master/src/main/resources/de/thetaphi/forbiddenapis/signatures/jdk-unsafe-1.6.txt#L47) shouldn't fail `...(Locale)`.  ([blog post](https://dzone.com/articles/policemans-horror-default) reference about forbiddenapis)

Comment: @cxw You are right. Project I was working on has two build systems: ant and maven. There were some files under target folder when I was using ant. So, ant clean were not able to delete that folder. You can write it as an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-check that the bytecode you are analyzing is actually your most recent build output, and that you're looking at the same line `forbiddenapis` is :) . This looks to me like your source/bytecode/analysis are falling out of sync — [the relevant rule](https://github.com/policeman-tools/forbidden-apis/blob/master/src/main/resources/de/thetaphi/forbiddenapis/signatures/jdk-unsafe-1.6.txt#L47) shouldn't flag an error on `String.toUpperCase(Locale)`.

Disclaimer: I haven't used `forbiddenapis` myself --- I wrote this answer based on the [repo](https://github.com/policeman-tools/forbidden-apis) and on a [blog post](https://dzone.com/articles/policemans-horror-default) I found.